# mount with cifs fails but destination is still accessible with sftp

Tags: mount, cifs

I had remote backup space mounted to my machine (Hetzner extra backup space for dedicated server).

It was mounted with cifs.

After restart I found that the mounted folder not accessible.

`ls -l`:

```
?---------   ? ?    ?        ?            ? backup
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 Nov 15  2011 bin
```

Where backup is a mounted folder.

I am able to `umount` it and after trying:

```
mount /backup
```

`mount` fails with timeout error.

I have `/etc/fstab` entry for `/backup` folder:

```
//<user>.your-backup.de/backup  /backup cifs user=<user>,password=<password> 0 0
```

If I try to connect with the same credentials via `sftp`, I succeed and have no problems.

Is there any way to debug mount to see what goes wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run [Wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) to obtain a trace of the network activity. Start capturing in Wireshark, attempt a mount, then stop capturing.

Wireshark can analyze and sort network traffic. Use the filter `tcp.port >= 137 && tcp.port <= 139` to select NetBios traffic. There are `smb.*` filters to view specific messages in the SMB protocol.